# showing that $\|f\|_1=\sup \{\int_{[a,b]}\tau(x)dx \mid \tau \text{ step function and } \tau\le f\} $

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, step-function

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$ and $f\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ a non-negative function. Is then
$$\|f\|_1=\sup \{\int_{[a,b]}\tau(x)dx \mid \tau \text{ step function and } \tau\le f\} ?$$
I have seen it to be true under additionally assuming that $f$ is Riemann-integrable. Therefore, I initially tried to find a counterexample (with a non Riemann-integrable function). But then I came across here [Lebesgue integrable implies Riemann integrable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2637080/lebesgue-integrable-implies-riemann-integrable), so that the equality probably is true (note that simple functions are more general as step functions!). And now I don't know whether it's true or not (I tend to vote for wrong, but I still don't have a counterexample)) .. 
I appreciate any help.

Comment: That's actually close to the definition of integral (in the Lebesgue sense) of a non-negative measurable function, where you consider simple functions in place of step functions, see [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch4.pdf).

Comment: It would be good if we are given a definition of $\|f\|_1.$ Is it $\|f\|_1 = \int_{[a,b]}|f(x)|\,dx?$

Comment: @Idonknow Oh sorry. yes, it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not true for all (Lebesgue) integrable functions.

Consider the indicator function on $[a,b]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$, namely $\mathbb{I}_{[a,b]\setminus \mathbb{Q}} : [a,b]\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ where $\mathbb{I}_{[a,b]\setminus \mathbb{Q}}(x)=1$ for $x\in [a,b]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and $0$ otherwise.

This function only differs from the indicator function on $[a,b]$ on countably many points, so 
$$
\int \mathbb{I}_{[a,b]\setminus \mathbb{Q}} = \int \mathbb{I}_{[a,b]}=b-a. 
$$
However clearly any step function $s:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $s\leq \mathbb{I}_{[a,b]\setminus \mathbb{Q}}$ maps into $(-\infty, 0]$.

It is true however for continuous functions on $[a,b]$, since [these are Riemann-integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56393/how-to-prove-that-continuous-functions-are-riemann-integrable).

Comment: I see, thank you.